# Play Services Realtime Multiplayer - Stops sending reliable messages

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

In my game, I create an auto-match room and I am successfully connected to my other device. Once the game has finished, I go through these steps again - All successful. However on the third attempt it will connect, but then the reliable messages are never received.

This has been with v17 of the library

I have tried on different devices (all 4.4 and above). But it always the same routine.

As an added bonus if I kill my game and launch again - it still fails to send messages, if I leave it 10-15mins I can connect and send messages again.

I have checked the developer console and I don't appear to be anywhere near the API limits.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Or does anyone know where to submit a bug for Play Services particular?

Comment: Did you get a solution James?

Comment: Afraid not. Sometimes it doesn't happen for a while. Then it happens. I guess it is their issue